# Number of full-rank binary matrices with given column Hamming weights

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields

What is the number of $m \times n$ matrices over $\mbox{GF}(2)$ that share the following constraints :

1. They have full rank ($\mbox{rank} = m$, given that $m<n$).
2. Their columns have the given Hamming weights $w_1, w_2, \dots, w_n$.

I have tried to solve this problem, It was easy when the first criterion was neglected as it would be a matter of permutations. However when we add the first criterion, it became hard for me to come up with a procedure that would ensure both constraints.

Comment: Your language is sloppy. If you actually mean the weights are all the same i.e., constant, say so, without writing out the $W_i$. The way it stands, it looks like you fix some set of column weights and will accept matrices which achieve that set of weights, subject to renumbering the columns.

Comment: Do you consider matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ or over $\mathrm{GF}(2)$? Something along [these lines](https://mathoverflow.net/q/264716) may work here.

Comment: This problem seems reminiscent of designing an LDPC code.  That problem is somewhat less constrained, and also fairly difficult, so I would find it surprising if you found a general solution to the problem.

Comment: Have you worked out answers for small values of $m$ and $n$? That might either lead you to an answer for your general question, or (more likely, I think) convince you that there is no useful answer to the fully general question.

Comment: Suppose that all the $w_i$'s are equal to $w$. Let $X$ be the set of all vectors in $\mathbb{F}_2^m$ of Hamming weight $w$. You are asking for the number of $n$-element spanning sets of $X$. Regard $X$ as a matroid (where independence is given by linear independence), For $w>2$ this matroid seems to be intractable, so I doubt that there is a nice answer to your question. For $w=2$ the matroid is well understood (see Sections 3 and 4 of https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/83.pdf), so there should be a nice answer.

Comment: When all the $w=2$, this is the number of $m$-edge forests on $n$ labeled vertices. So $n^{n-2}$ if $m = n-1$, and https://oeis.org/A138464 more generally.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: I was incorrectly thinking about $\mathbb{R}^m$, not $\mathbb{F}_2^m$, when I made my comment about $w=2$.

Comment: Oh, whoops, it isn't just forests. It's also okay for any of the components to be a unicyclic grah with an odd cycle. Okay, this is not going to give  nice answer even for $w=2$.